# RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool when running Union

Tags: arcpy, layers, union, python-3, runtimeerror

I have a list of a 2 layers (`nfhl_fld_haz_features`, `prelim_fld_haz_features`) and a feature class (`master_merge`) that I want to perform a union on:

```
 wkflw2_union = arcpy.Union_analysis([master_merge, nfhl_fld_haz_features, prelim_fld_haz_features], wkflw2_union_output)
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       wkflw2_union = arcpy.Union_analysis([master_merge, nfhl_fld_haz_features, prelim_fld_haz_features], wkflw2_union_output)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 734, in
>   Union
>       raise e
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 731, in
>   Union
>       retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Union_analysis(*gp_fixargs((in_features,
>   out_feature_class, join_attributes, cluster_tolerance, gaps), True)))
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing_base.py", line
>   496, in 
>       return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
>
> RuntimeError: Object:  Error in executing tool

I don't see any issue with using a list, but could this error be due to using a feature class mixed with 2 layers? Or could this be something else (the main files come from a network drive)

Comment: To confirm, all three inputs are polygons?  (And you can perform a test with your union to answer the question about mixing feature classes and layers by making a layer from the third input.)

Comment: Yes, they are all polygons. I've got a suspicion that this is some kind of network or server issue related to grabbing the files. I've had a similar issue before where someone else was accessing the same source file and a Runtime Error was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to have parameters like file paths in input list. 
As far as understood `master_merge` is something like `r"D:\work\file.gdb\master_merge"` and let it be like this.

Paths to layers can be obtained with Describe function and catalogPath method.
So you have:

```
master_merge = r"D:\work\file.gdb\master_merge"
wkflw2_union_output r"D:\work\file.gdb\union_out"

nfhl_fld_fc = arcpy.Describe('nfhl_fld_haz_features').catalogPath
prelim_fld_fc = arcpy.Describe('prelim_fld_haz_features').catalogPath

wkflw2_union = arcpy.Union_analysis([master_merge, nfhl_fld_fc, prelim_fld_fc], wkflw2_union_output)
```